# How to prove that two PDE's are related?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde, parabolic-pde, dispersive-pde

Say that I have PDE a)

$U_x+U_y=\alpha U$

then I have PDE b)

$U_{xx}+U_{yy}=\beta U$

It is obvious that the first and the second are related by that they are composed of two operators which differ  by one degree of differentiation. However, how can I prove that the solutions are related too, and are they?

I was thinking of looking at if the PDEs are hyperbolic, parabolic or elliptic. But I am not sure that is the way to prove it. Also, I am not sure what is the criteria for that two PDEs are "related".

Sorry, I have no more to add, since I am not an expert on PDE theory.

Thanks

Comment: I think you'd need to supply a definition of `related' for this to make sense (if there is a standard definition, I am not aware of it). Note that: 1) a PDE should be supplied with boundary conditions to form a well posed problem. Your first equation requires $U$ to be specified on some line in the $xy$ plane, while your second requires $U$ to be specified on the boundary enclosing the solution region. These are quite different.

Comment: 2) Your first equation is not elliptic; there are no first order elliptic PDEs [except with complex coefficients in 2D](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232398/is-there-any-elliptic-operator-of-first-order-in-u-subset-mathbb-rn). This means that the qualitative behavior of solutions to the two equations is different.

Comment: 3) Sometimes a second order equation may be factorized to yield first order equations, for example [the wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#General_solution). In this way, in principle, studying the second equation might lead you to an equation similar to the first- but I do not think that is the case for your examples.

Comment: Assume that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ commute with one another, would that be a useful property to relate these two equations to one another?

Comment: I suppose you could try to show that solutions of one PDE are necessarily solutions of another by manipulating the equations: but doing so you must, eg. differentiate *both* sides. Despite the formal similarity, there is no obvious mapping between the operators $\partial_x+\partial_y-1$ and $\partial_{xx}+\partial_{yy}-1$, which is I think what you're asking in the examples of OP? Also, by solving the first equation, you can show that for (only) some special choices of initial conditions, the solutions of your first equation do satisfy the second

Comment: Thanks , this is the answer I looked for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$U_x+U_y=\alpha U \tag 1$$
The solution of Eq.$(1)$ is easy to find thanks to the method of characteristics (or other method) :
$$U(x,y)=e^{\alpha x}\Phi(x-y)$$
$\Phi$ is an arbitrary function until some boundary condition be specified.

$U_x=\alpha e^{\alpha x}\Phi+e^{\alpha x}\Phi'$

$U_y=-e^{\alpha x}\Phi'$

$U_{xx}=\alpha^2 e^{\alpha x}\Phi+2\alpha e^{\alpha x}\Phi'+e^{\alpha x}\Phi''$

$U_{yy}=e^{\alpha x}\Phi''$

Putting them into Eq.$(2)$ leads to :

$$U_{xx}+U_{yy}=\beta U \tag 2$$

$\alpha^2 e^{\alpha x}\Phi+2\alpha e^{\alpha x}\Phi'+e^{\alpha x}\Phi''=\beta e^{\alpha x}\Phi$

$$(\alpha^2-\beta) \Phi+2\alpha \Phi'+\Phi''=0\tag 3$$

This is not true in general (any $\alpha,\beta,\Phi$). Thus a relationship between Eqs.$(1)$ and $(2)$ doesn't exist in general.

The solutions of Eqs.$(1)$ and $(2)$ are consistent only in the particular case of solutions of Eq.$(3)$ if :

$\Phi(x-y))=c_1\exp\left((-\alpha+\sqrt{\beta})(x-y) \right)+c_2\exp\left((-\alpha-\sqrt{\beta})(x-y) \right) \tag 4$

In this particular case the common solution of Eqs.$(1)$ and $(2)$ is :
$$U(x,y)=c_1e^{\alpha x}\exp\left((-\alpha+\sqrt{\beta})(x-y) \right) + c_2e^{\alpha x}\exp\left((-\alpha-\sqrt{\beta})(x-y) \right) \tag 5$$

Comment: Thanks for this ! Does this mean that the two PDEs share a familiarity on a certain set of solutions? If yes,  can one say that the two PDEs share a spectral region?

Comment: In general the two PDE doesn't share a set of solutions. All depends on the boundary conditions. If the boundary conditions implies that the function $\Phi$ is on the form of Eq.$(4)$ the two PDE share the set of solutions $(5)$.

Comment: Got it, thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

Take the four operators given in the OP:

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}=A$

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}=B$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=C$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}=D$

The Da Prato-Grisvard theorem $^1$ states that we can find the sum of two operators A, B, where $A+B$ with natural domain $\mathscr{D}(A+B) =
\mathscr{D}(A)\cup\mathscr{D}(B)$. Here, $\mathscr{D}(A)\cup\mathscr{D}(B)$ has similar properties as A and B and one obtains the important feature
that the method can be iterated, and hence, complicated operators can be built up from simpler ones. If the operators are non-commuting, matters are, naturally, much more involved. A and B do not commute, and also C and D do not commute, since their order of operation would give different outcomes. However, the Da Prato-Grisvard theorem remains valid if A and
B satisfy certain commutator estimates $^2$.

One can find $\mathscr{D}(A)\cup\mathscr{D}(B)$ and see if it admits a $H^\infty$ calcululs (to see what this means, see ref $^3$) and then do the same for the  $\mathscr{D}(C)\cup\mathscr{D}(D)$ sum, and if both admit a  $H^\infty$ calcululs, one has proven that the two PDEs have some conserved familiarity.

A second option is to use the Dore-Venni theorem$^4$ to find the sum of two non-commuting operators for the case of PDE 1 and PDE 2.

1. G. Da Prato, P. Grisvard. Sommes d’opératours linéaires et équations différentielles
   opérationelles, J. Math. Pures Appl. 54 (1975), 305–387. MR0442749 (56:1129)
2. Burrage, Kevin, and P. M. Burrage. "General order conditions for stochastic Runge-Kutta methods for both commuting and non-commuting stochastic ordinary differential equation systems." Applied Numerical Mathematics 28.2-4 (1998): 161-177.

https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2007-359-08/S0002-9947-07-04291-2/S0002-9947-07-04291-2.pdf

3. Hytönen, Tuomas, et al. "The H∞-functional calculus." Analysis in Banach Spaces. Springer, Cham, 2017. 359-478.  https://helda.helsinki.fi/bitstream/handle/10138/327524/hytonen_Ch10.pdf?sequence=1
4. S. Monniaux, J. Prüss. A theorem of the Dore-Venni type for non-commuting operators.
   Transactions Amer. Math. Soc. 349 (1997), 4787–4814. MR1433125 (98b:47005)